# PDO unable to insert datas into database

Tags: php, pdo

I'm newbie with pdo. Here i'm trying to insert the datas into database using this below coding. But, i cannot able to insert the datas into database. I'm getting this following error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

I searched on SO and internet about this error. Some people says add `global $conn;` at the top of your code. I added these code but i'm getting same error. Anyone tell me what should i do if i want to clear this error?

**Config.php**

```
      <?php
            $user = "root";
            $password = "password";

            try
            {
                $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=evouchers', $user, $password);
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                'DATABASE CONNECTION ERROR' .$e->getMessage();
            }
        ?>

    **Database.php**

        <?php
            session_start();

            include('config.php');

                if(isset($_POST['submit_val']))
                {
                    $cmeal = $_POST['meal'];
                    try
                    {
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ebmealplans ( MealPlanName, CreatedOn ) VALUES ( :cmeal, NOW() )");
                        $conn->errorInfo();
                        $stmt->bindParam(':cmeal', $cmeal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->execute();
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e)
                    {
                        'Query failed to insert into database ' .$e->getMessage();
                    }

                    $croom = $_POST['room'];
                    $ref_key = $conn->lastInsertId();
                    try
                    {
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ebroomtypes ( RoomTypeName, CreatedOn ) VALUES ( :croom, NOW() )");
                        $conn->errorInfo();
                        $stmt->bindParam(':croom', $croom, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->execute();
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e)
                    {
                        'Query failed to insert into database ' .$e->getMessage();
                    }


<*************** UPDATED CODES ***************>


  $creference = $_POST['reference'];
            $crefdate = $_POST['refdate'];
            $ccin = $_POST['cin'];
            $cout = $_POST['out'];
            $cgname = $_POST['gname'];
            $ctotaladults = $_POST['totaladults'];
            $cchildrens = $_POST['childrens'];
            $cinfants = $_POST['infants'];
            $cgphone = $_POST['gphone'];
            $cgemail = $_POST['gemail'];
            $cgfax = $_POST['gfax'];
            $cgaddress1 = $_POST['gaddress1'];
            $cgaddress2 = $_POST['gaddress2'];
            $cregion = $_POST['region'];
            $ccity = $_POST['city'];
            $cstate = $_POST['city_state'];
            $ccountry = $_POST['country'];
            $ccurrency = $_POST['currency'];
            $ccurrencyto = $_POST['tocurrency'];
            $camount = $_POST['camount'];
            $ccurrencyvalue = $_POST['currencyvalue'];
            $voucher_fk = $conn->lastInsertId();
            try
            {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ebvouchers ( VoucherReference, BookingDate, CheckIndate, CheckOutDate, MealPlanID_Fk, RoomTypeID_Fk, GuestName, TotalAdults, Childrens, Infants, GuestPhone, GuestEmail, GuestFax, GuestAddressLine1, GuestAddressLine2, GuestRegion, GuestCity, GuestState, GuestCountry, GuestCurrency, GuestCurrencyTo, CurrencyAmount, GuestCurrencyValue, VoucherCreatedOn ) VALUES ( :reference, :refdate, :ccin, :cout, :r_key, :r_key, :gname, :totaladults, :childrens, :infants, :gphone, :gemail, :gfax, :gaddress1, :gaddress2, :gregion, :city, :state, :country, :currency, :currencyto, :amount, :currencyvalue, NOW() )");
                $conn->errorInfo();
                $stmt->bindParam(':reference', $creference, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':refdate', $crefdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':ccin', $ccin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':cout', $cout, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':r_key', $ref_key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':r_key', $ref_key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':gname', $cgname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':totaladults', $ctotaladults, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':childrens', $cchildrens, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':infants', $cinfants, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':gphone', $cgphone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':gemail', $cgemail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':gfax', $cgfax, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':gaddress1', $cgaddress1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':gaddress2', $cgaddress2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':gregion', $cregion, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':city', $ccity, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':state', $cstate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':country', $ccountry, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':currency', $ccurrency, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':currencyto', $ccurrencyto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':amount', $camount, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':currencyvalue', $ccurrencyvalue, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                'Query failed to insert into database ' .$e->getMessage();
            }

<*************** UPDATED CODES ***************>

                    foreach ( $_POST['slno'] as $key=>$slno )
                    {
                        $date = $_POST['date'][$key];
                        $particulars = $_POST['particulars'][$key];
                        $noofnights = $_POST['noofnights'][$key];
                        $rate = $_POST['rate'][$key];
                        $price = $_POST['price'][$key];
                        $tax = $_POST['tax'][$key];
                        $nettotal = $_POST['nettotal'];
                        $totalamount = $_POST['totalamount'];
                        $finaltotal = $_POST['finaltotal'];
                        $c_date = $date;
                        $c_slno = $slno;
                        $c_particulars = $particulars;
                        $c_noofnights = $noofnights;
                        $c_rate = $rate;
                        $c_price = $price;
                        $c_tax = $tax;
                        $c_nettotal = $nettotal;
                        $c_totalamount = $totalamount;
                        $c_finaltotal = $finaltotal;

                        try
                        {
                            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ebvouchertariffs ( TariffSlNo, TariffDate, TariffParticulars, NoOfNights, TariffRate, TariffPrice, TariffTax, TariffNetTotal, TariffAddTotal, TariffFinalTotal, VoucherID_Fk, CreatedOn ) VALUES ( :c_slno, :c_date, :c_particulars, :c_noofnights, :c_rate, :c_price, :c_tax, :c_nettotal, :c_totalamount, :c_finaltotal, :voucher_fk, NOW() )");
                        $conn->errorInfo();
                        $stmt->bindParam(':c_slno', $c_slno, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':c_date', $c_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':c_particulars', $c_particulars, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':c_noofnights', $c_noofnights, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':c_rate', $c_rate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':c_price', $c_price, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':c_tax', $c_tax, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':c_nettotal', $c_nettotal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':c_totalamount', $c_totalamount, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':c_finaltotal', $c_finaltotal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':voucher_fk', $voucher_fk, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        }
                        catch(PDOException $e)
                        {
                            'Query failed to insert into database ' .$e->getMessage();
                        }

                        $conn = null;

                        }
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Where is your declaration of $conn?

Comment: **Data**  is plural and uncountable!!

Comment: @undone : plural means? can't understand

Comment: what's in config.php?

Comment: Means you can't use **datas**:-D

Comment: @rccoros : declaration of $conn? i didn't declare $conn here..

Comment: @Class : update my question.. in config.php i have the database connection..

Comment: PHP has pretty liberal scoping rules, but in this case I think you need to use globals ... which are bad.

Comment: @ta.speot.is : how to use globals in this code?

Comment: Check your database  connection. there is something wrong there. May be wrong credential

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @AwladLiton : above i posted my database connection code (config.php). i think db connection is working fine..

Comment: @user3181207: i have tested it locally with my database connection. it is working and if i give something wrong credential then it gives your given error

Comment: @user3181207:  var_dump($conn); what you have got?

Comment: @AwladLiton : i got this `object(PDO)#1 (0) { }` when i use `var_dump($conn)`;

Comment: remove this line   $conn = null;

Comment: When you catch `PDOException` you do not *do* anything with the error (it is just a useless statement that is thrown away), which is why it is not defined in `Database.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not print your exception. If you have any exception you will not get it.  and i think problem in your `$conn= null;` 
$conn = null; this line makes your connection object invalid and after executing this line you have invalid pdo object.for this you have got this error in loop. it should execute all other query before this line is executed. just remove this line. and print your exception message like this:

**Try this:**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include('config.php');

        if(isset($_POST['submit_val']))
        {
            $cmeal = $_POST['meal'];
            try
            {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ebmealplans ( MealPlanName, CreatedOn ) VALUES ( :cmeal, NOW() )");
                $conn->errorInfo();
                $stmt->bindParam(':cmeal', $cmeal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                die('Query failed to insert into database ' .$e->getMessage());
            }

            $croom = $_POST['room'];
            $ref_key = $conn->lastInsertId();
            try
            {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ebroomtypes ( RoomTypeName, CreatedOn ) VALUES ( :croom, NOW() )");
                $conn->errorInfo();
                $stmt->bindParam(':croom', $croom, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
               die( 'Query failed to insert into database ' .$e->getMessage());
            }

            foreach ( $_POST['slno'] as $key=>$slno )
            {
                $date = $_POST['date'][$key];
                $particulars = $_POST['particulars'][$key];
                $noofnights = $_POST['noofnights'][$key];
                $rate = $_POST['rate'][$key];
                $price = $_POST['price'][$key];
                $tax = $_POST['tax'][$key];
                $nettotal = $_POST['nettotal'];
                $totalamount = $_POST['totalamount'];
                $finaltotal = $_POST['finaltotal'];
                $c_date = $date;
                $c_slno = $slno;
                $c_particulars = $particulars;
                $c_noofnights = $noofnights;
                $c_rate = $rate;
                $c_price = $price;
                $c_tax = $tax;
                $c_nettotal = $nettotal;
                $c_totalamount = $totalamount;
                $c_finaltotal = $finaltotal;

                try
                {
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ebvouchertariffs ( TariffSlNo, TariffDate, TariffParticulars, NoOfNights, TariffRate, TariffPrice, TariffTax, TariffNetTotal, TariffAddTotal, TariffFinalTotal, VoucherID_Fk, CreatedOn ) VALUES ( :c_slno, :c_date, :c_particulars, :c_noofnights, :c_rate, :c_price, :c_tax, :c_nettotal, :c_totalamount, :c_finaltotal, :voucher_fk, NOW() )");
                $conn->errorInfo();
                $stmt->bindParam(':c_slno', $c_slno, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':c_date', $c_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':c_particulars', $c_particulars, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':c_noofnights', $c_noofnights, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':c_rate', $c_rate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':c_price', $c_price, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':c_tax', $c_tax, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':c_nettotal', $c_nettotal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':c_totalamount', $c_totalamount, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':c_finaltotal', $c_finaltotal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':voucher_fk', $voucher_fk, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    die('Query failed to insert into database ' .$e->getMessage());
                }

                //$conn = null;

                }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: same error - Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Comment: on which line? can you give me this line?

Comment: yes i replaced my config.php code. but getting same error online number 59. Line number 59 is -> `$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ebvouchertariffs ( TariffSlNo, TariffDate, TariffParticulars, NoOfNights, TariffRate, TariffPrice, TariffTax, TariffNetTotal, TariffAddTotal, TariffFinalTotal, VoucherID_Fk, CreatedOn ) VALUES ( :c_slno, :c_date, :c_particulars, :c_noofnights, :c_rate, :c_price, :c_tax, :c_nettotal, :c_totalamount, :c_finaltotal, :voucher_fk, NOW() )");`

Comment: @user3181207: did you remove this line $conn = null; ? did you paste my code in your database.php?

Comment: i've updated my question again. i changed my code as what you said in above comments. Now, i'm facing a weird problem here. i can able to insert the datas into the database. you can see four database tables in this coding `ebmealplans`, `ebroomtypes`, `ebvouchers` and `ebvouchertariffs`. `ebvouchers` table cannot able to insert the datas into database and remaining tables are inserted the datas perfectly? i did't get any error too. i'm confused. you can see in this coding inside the <*************** UPDATE CODES ***************>

Comment: @user3181207 : i have updated my answer. read it and fix it. i think you will be able to understand what is the problem. You should not have this line : $conn = null; it makes $conn object invalid. Remove it from your code it should work fine

Comment: @user3181207: Then it should work. Just paste my above code in your database.php and test it

Comment: Oh @awlad liton. I understand... its working man.. But one table didn't insert the datas. That is why i'm asking you again and again. i've update my codes. please check my codes again `ebmealplans`, `ebroomtypes`, `ebvouchertariffs` is working fine. `ebvouchers` table not working (didn't insert the datas).

Comment: i can not see any query that inserted data to table ebvouchers in your code

Comment: @user3181207 can you told me in which line you are trying to insert data in ebvouchers table?

Comment: i've made a few silly mistakes here. now, i changed it. its working now. your answers is also useful. Then how to close the database connection at the end of the query. In mysql we are using mysql_close($conn); here how can i close the db connection?

Comment: i see you have error in this:  $voucher_fk = $conn->lastInsertId();

Comment: its working fine now. i'm using this $voucher_fk for reference to another table..

Comment: can you please clear my doubts? i'm trying to insert the datas into database using above coding. But everyone uses some function and put the code inside the function, they use some global variables like this global `$conn`. is it necessary to use code inside the function? or is above my coding is enough?

Comment: i think it should be okay. you also can use function .